# How to display Xcode output on Terminal?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal

How do I run a C programming language from Xcode on terminal? Please help me with this by answering a step by step procedure in doing this. Thanks.

Version 10.7.5 on a Macbook Air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode isn't intended to run the program so that it displays its output in an external program like Terminal.app. It could probably be done by messing with the scheme configuration, but it's probably not a good idea.

If you want a program's output to appear in Terminal.app then you should run the program in Terminal. To do this go to your project's build directory, find the executable and then copy the path into Terminal. Run the program.

---

Given your comment it's not clear what you're asking. It sounds like maybe you're asking if the commands passed to `system()` can also be used directly when running Terminal.app. The answer to that question is 'yes'.

You give an example `system("cls")`. If you're attempting to run the command `cls` in Terminal.app and finding that it doesn't work, the reason for that it's a Windows command. `system("cls")` works only on Windows, and the command `cls` can also be used directly in cmd.exe on Windows. `system("cls")` does not work on OS X, nor does a command `cls` work in Terminal.app.

The command that works in Terminal.app to clear the screen is `clear`, and if you want to use this command from inside a C program you can use `system("clear")`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will keep this in mind. I am just asking this question because I was curious if a command for C on Xcode would work on Terminal. system("cls");

Comment: `"cls"` won't work because that's for Windows. But if you use commands for OS X then `system` should work fine. E.g. `system("echo Hello World")`.

Answer (score 1):

Write xcode output to file and run `tail -f` in terminal.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *nsp = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *logPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xcode.log",NSHomeDirectory()];
    freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation], "a", stderr);
    [nsp release];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}  
$ tail -f /homeDir/xcode.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type below keys while you're in in terminal, and it will clear the logs:

**Command + K**